# Eliminar numeros de una cadena de palabras

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una pregunta ¿existe alguna forma de eliminar los digitos de una cadena?
Se que puedes convertir la cadena a una lista e ir recorriendo la lista con un bucle, e ir guardando los trozos en otra cadena para quitar los  números. Pero tengo un servidor que me manda cadenas con números y palabras, el servidor va cortando el mensaje como le da la gana, y lo que necesito es ir concatenando el mensaje, pero el caso es que al convertirlo fuera del bucle en lista e ir quitando los numeros, no me lo concatena bien.

Tengo dos preguntas que me rondan en la cabeza, la primera es la ya mencionada antes.

> inicialmente tengo esto "oidas 45 66 32 djhid qw eqwe qqwda ero es 864" y quiero eliminar directamente los digitos de la cadena sin convertir la cadena a lista y tratarla. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo directamente?
>
> Mi otra pregunta es ¿hay alguna forma de saber si ha cortado el servidor esa palabra? Por que si la palabra la ha cortado, me gustaria que se concatenase bien. Pero está la posibilidad de que el segundo mensaje empiece por un espacio por que lo ha cortado al terminar la palabra.

Comment: ¿Que pasa con los espacios entre los números? ¿Los dejas?

Comment: Si, los espacios se deben mantener como están.

Comment: `cad.replace("0","").replace("1","").replace("2","").replace("3",""),,,,,,replace("9","")`

Answer (score 5):

Las cadenas son inmutables por lo que no hay forma de eliminar los caracteres de la propia cadena, necesitas crear otra. No necesitas una lista para nada, si solo quieres eliminar los caracteres que sean un dígito (0-9), basta con iterar sobre cada carácter y filtrar usando `str.isdigit`. Luego unes los caracteres de nuevo usando `str.join`:

```
palabra = "oidas 45 66 32 djhid qw eqwe qqwda ero es 864"
palabra = "".join(char for char in palabra if not char.isdigit())
```

> ```
> >>> palabra
> 'oidas    djhid qw eqwe qqwda ero es '
> ```

Si alguien es un apasionado de la programación funcional se puede usr `filter`:

```
palabra = "".join(filter(lambda char: not char.isdigit(), palabra))
```

También recurrir a `re.sub`:

```
import re

palabra = re.sub("\d+", "", palabra)
```

Comment: Pero una pregunta, el espacio monumental que hay entre oidas y djhid, no se puede remplazar por un espacio simple. Se que se pude utilizar replace, pero claro no se cuantos espacios ha dejado al quiar los numeros.

Comment: Y una pregunta, no hay ninguna forma de saber si lo concatena bien?

Comment: Por eso comentaba lo de los espacios antes... Esos espacios son los que había entre los número. Se puede quitar pero ya la cosa se complica ¿Que pasa con el espacio final por ejemplo (el que hay después de "es")? Es decir, aprte de eliminar espacios duplicados, eliminamos los posibles espacios que queden al inicio o final trás eliminar los números si estos estaban al inicio o final de la cadena?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si el servidor envió  "123 qqwda     ero 45 " que debería quedar `" qqwda     ero",  "qqwda ero", " qqwda     ero  ",  " qqwda     ero ", "qqwda ero ",` etc... Tocar los espacios como vez ya no es tan simple como eleimnar los digitos

Answer (score 0):

Usando regex, podrias agregar el espacio antes del numero en la busqueda

```py
import re

re.sub('\s?\d', '', 'oidas 45 66 32 djhid qw eqwe qqwda ero es 864')
```

> 'oidas djhid qw eqwe qqwda ero es'